# Characterization of trivial vector bundle on projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle on the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that all the cohomology groups

$$H^*(E(-1))=H^*(E(-2))=\cdots=H^*(E(-n))=0\,.$$

The claim is that $E$ is the trivial vector bundle. How to prove this. Are there any hints.

Comment: Use Beilinson spectral sequence.

Comment: @Sasha, is there no obvious way?

Comment: There shouldn't be a completely obvious way, since this fact is essentially equivalent to fullness of the Beilinson's exceptional collection.

Comment: Use induction on $n$, for $n=1$, this being trivial.